# Three.js (r75) - Why THREE.Geometry does not have an array for storing edges?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, three.js, edges

I know there are ways to draw edges, but what's the reason why `THREE.Geometry` only has an array for vertices and one for faces?

I was looking at [this example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Topology-Data.html) and I found it useful to have an array of edges, in this way accessing them is a lot easier.

Comment: that would be redundant, THREE does not use edges internally and edges are not used very often, arguing that it would be convenient in some example is not right as you would waste memory and processor time in majority of other instances, arguing that it has faces is also bad as they are used internally in the core functionality

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik -  I've imagined that. So the reason why a BMesh (Blender Mesh) sotores vertices, faces, edges and loops is just because it runs as desktop app so it has more resources to play with?

Comment: BMesh supports polygon faces with N sides while THREE only uses triangles, also blender makes use of the edges as they are interactable in the editor itself, THREE is not an editor, it is a tool for easier access to webgl, you can create your own geometry class inside THREE that has edges that are kept updated or reference their vertices, but that is way too specific use and special use cases should not be in the core of a library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometry data structure does not contain edges because edges are not, in general, needed for rendering.

three.js has utilities that can help you, however.

If you look at the source code for `EdgesGeometry` you can see how to create and access the edges.

The same can be said for `WireframeGeometry`.

three.js r.84